# Does project lombok works in jboss developer studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, lombok

Is it possible to install project lombok in jboss developer studio?

When i run lombok.jar, i can only install it into a real eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: I found the anser: It got it working by copying the lombok.jar to the installation folder and by adding the following settings to the jdevstudio.ini file:

    -javaagent:lombok.jar
    -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar

Comment: I understand that jboss developer studio is a customized eclipse? If so, please create an issue in http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/list so we can detect it. Can you include the default folder name as well as the name if the executable and ini file? Disclosure: I am one of the lombok developers.

Comment: I opened https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=752&thanks=752&ts=1416438588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but according to the source code since Lombok version 0.11.8 (released April 2013) the Lombok installer recognizes jboss developer studio.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Answer (score 3):

You can Add it. I am using with my Jboss developer studio.

1. Add jar to your classpath
2. Make sure you enable annotation processing
3. double click on lambok jar, it will automatically find the installed IDE, then     click on proceed.
4. Restart IDE